# Decode Cyrillic strings

Tags: linux, character-encoding

How to decode strings on a text files like this:

```
Âèòàëèé
```

This analyzer (https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) detected the source encoding  as **WINDOWS-1251 + displayed as ISO-8859-1**, and successfully decodes to desired `Виталий`

My question is, how can I set up iconv to decode it properly? For `iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t ISO-8859-1 filename`, i get Aeoaeee

Answer (score 1):

Considering your locale is based on UTF-8, this will work:

```bsh
echo "Âèòàëèé" | iconv -t ISO-8859-1 | iconv -f CP1251
Виталий
```